# Using plural in Zend_Translate (Array adapter)

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-translate, pluralize

Can anybody show me example of using Zend_Translate with Array Adapter when I need to make more than one plural forms for a word. For 1 entity first, for 2 - 4 entities second, for 5 and more - third form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Zend_Translate does not do pluralization/inflection but only translation.

Comment: $translates = array('car' => array('car', '2 cars', 'X carss'));
$_ = new Zend_Translate('array', $translates, 'ru');
$number = 3;
echo $_->translate(array('car', $number, 'ru'));
Such example works for $number = 1 or 2, but not for value of 3 and more